# How to write job scheduler in angular 6?

Tags: java, angular

Currently we are using java scheduler but we want to stop java scheduler  and want use any other better scheduler.
Can you please any one suggest me on this. Front end application is angular 6

Answer (score 1):

If you have written your Jobs in Java (I suppose they were running in backend), then it does not make sense to run them in Angular (which is running in frontend).

If you want to run cronjobs in nodejs applications, i would suggest to use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: yes your correct but we want stop completely java in my application

Comment: Which framework/language do you want to use in backend?

Comment: you can use nodeJs at server side and a lot of npm packages are there , like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron